# Proof: each subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is of the form $\{\overline d,\overline{2d},\dots,\overline{n-d},\overline n\}$, where $d$ divides $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Show that each subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is of the form
>   $\{\overline d,\overline{2d},\dots,\overline{n-d},\overline n\}$,
>   where $d$ is a divisor of $n$.

I’m assuming they’re talking about non-trivial subgroups here? Anyhow, I'll line out the proof my book provides:

Let $K=\{a\in\mathbb Z\mid\overline a\in H\}$. They show this is a subgroup, so we have $K=d\mathbb Z$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$. However, they argue that since $n\in K=d\mathbb Z$, it follows that $d\mid n$. That makes sense to me, but I fail to see how this holds in an example.

Say we have $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$ and we take $n=2$. Then our subgroup is simply the entire group, but $2$ doesn’t divide $7$. So I'm missing something, but I don't see what. Could someone help?

Comment: In other words, the subgroups are $d\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ where $d\mid n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $2$ doesn't divide $7$. But as you said the subgroup you get is the entire group, which can be written in the form $\{\bar{1},\bar{2},\dots,\bar{6}\}$ with $1\mid 7$, so that's not a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark**: Every subgroup of a cyclic group is again cyclic.

---

Now suppose that $H \leq \mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$ be any aritrary subgroup;

let's denote it's genereator by $t$; now let $d:=\gcd(t,n)$; 
then we have:

$$H = <t> = <d> .$$

---

In your specefic case, we have 
$d=\gcd(2,7)=1$ :

$$  <2> = <1> .$$

Answer (score 0):

If you take $G = \mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$, your "theorem" says that the subgroups are of the form $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$, where $d$ divides $7$. That means the subgroups are $\{0\}$ and $G$.

Comment: So if you take $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ then according to what you said, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, whereas you don't even have $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Whereas with what she wrote: $\{\bar{2},\bar{4},\bar{6}\}$, which contains $3$ elements, whereas $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ contains $2$ elements.

Comment: @Scientifica, but you have monomorphism $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. Every cyclic group is either $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z$, up to isomorphism. In this case, subgroup $\{\bar 0,\bar 3\}$ of $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Ennar That's right, and saying "subgroups isomorphic to" instead of "subgroups are of the form" solves the problem. I just insisted on that because the OP talks about the form $\{\bar{d},\dots\}$. Besides, this answer doesn't answer the OP's question about what she's missing.

Comment: @Scientifica, it is very common to identify isomorphic groups and act as if monomorphism is inclusion. For example, we say that $\mathbb Z\subseteq \mathbb Q$, but if you constructed $\mathbb Q$ the usual way as field of fractions of $\mathbb Z$, then $\mathbb Z\not\subseteq \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Ennar Yes you are right. Now that you say that, I realize I might have misinterpreted what the answerer meant by "are of the form".

Comment: @Scientifica, though, it is possible that OP might have been confused by that, so your remark is still a good one, and this exchange will hopefully be of use to them.